# Strange behavior of excel 2007 on WinXP

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-excel

I'm on a machine that had quite some bloat ware and no update in ages. I made all the updates, removed the bloatware and cleaned using ccleaner.

So far so good. Now excel shows some really strange behavior when I open .xls files through windows. The current behavior is: it opens a new excel process window which will then stay empty. One has then to drag the xls file into the window to open it.

I would like to restore the default behavior. So far I have tried:

- running the Microsoft Office Diagnosis
- copied excel related registry keys from a machine with working excel and imported them
- had a look into the registry entry for .xls files myself - which seems correct.

It was of no use and I'm out of ideas. I would try to avoid a reinstall as we have a very bureaucratic IT department and the machine then would be gone for some undetermined time period.

So any idea what to do would be great.

Comment: I would try using the repair feature within the Office installer. To do this, go to Add/Remove programs section of the Control Panel, select Office in the list and choose *Change* then *Repair*.

Comment: Just tried, and restarted. Unfortunately still the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try again but when Excel opens (with no .xls file) press and hold "Control and F10" (or F9) just once (this minimizes/maximizes the xls file).

I've had similar and due to our dual screen, the .xls file was loading but not within the "view".

**EDIT**
Or, it's a file association issue.

Try

First, open any folder in Windows XP.

Click on the Tools menu, and choose Folder Options.

From the dialog that pops up, click the File Types tab. You will now be presented with a list of all document types recognized by your computer.

Scroll down to XLS, select it, and click the Advanced button. Now you'll see several "Actions" registered for Excel worksheets.

Usually, Open is the default (indicated by being in bold). Select "Open" and click the Edit button.

The main piece of data in here is the field labeled "Application used to perform action". This should point to your Excel executable, followed by some command-line arguments. Here's how it appears on my PC: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\EXCEL.EXE" /e "%1"

It is very important to make sure that the %1 is surrounded by quotes. %1 is the variable representing the full path and file name of the document you are opening. If it contains any spaces, and this is not surrounded by quotes you will get a flurry of weird errors.

"Use DDE" is normally checked. Now, make sure that "DDE Message" is empty. Click OK.

Click OK back at the Edit File Type dialog. Click Close on the Folder Options dialog.

Comment: I tried. F9 does nothing here. But F10 leads to a "flicker". But no document loaded. Keep in mind if I open by dragging the file into excel the content is displayed correct.

Comment: Oh - didn't see that edit. That solved it! I'm a bit curios what made the DDE entry in the first place.

Comment: and I'm afraid I have no idea as to why! Ha ha, I'd be rich if I did :) I'm glad it now works for you.